# Suppose {A} is a sequence that assumes only integer values, under what conditions does this sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to think of this question. Could it be a sequence that eventually repeats the same digit over and over again? How would I explain this?

Comment: Ultimately constant.

Comment: eventually constant, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511068/convergence-of-a-constant-sequence-and-an-eventually-constant-sequence

Comment: Do you mean the **sequence** $a_n$, or the **series** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$?

Answer (score 2):

Literally going to the definition:

{$a_n$} $\rightarrow b$ means for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that $n > N \implies $ $|a_n - b| < \epsilon$.

Okay,  Let $\epsilon = .01$ or anything small.  There is an $N$ such that $n,m > N$ implies

$|a_n - b| < .01$.  So $|a_n - a_m| < |a_n - b| + |a_m - b| < .02$.

So we have two *integers* such that $|a_n - a_m| < .02$.

If $a_n$ is an integer and $a_m$ is an integer then $a_n - a_m =c_{n,m}$ is an integer.

What integer is $|c_{n,m}| < .02$?  The only such integer is 0.  so $|a_n - a_m| = 0$ so $a_n = a_m$ for all $n,m > N$.

So $a_n = b$ for some constant integer $b$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 0):

As you suppose, this means that the $a_n$'s, after a while, just keep a constant value and are all equal to each other (the sequence is ultimately constant).

**To show it:** assume $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence of integers converging to some limit $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$, and use the $\varepsilon$-definition of convergence.

In particular, instantiate it for $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{3}$. What does that imply for the $a_n$'s?

(Recall that if $a,b$ are two distinct integers, then $\lvert a-b\rvert \geq 1$, and therefore $\lvert a-\ell\rvert + \lvert b-\ell\rvert \geq 1$.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a sequence that repeats itself over and over again is a legitimate sequence that converges to the value that's being repeated. You can use the standard definition of convergence to show that that's the case.

Comment: "Over and over again" is vague. It could mean that every term is eventually equal to the value, or the value occurs infinitely often, or it occurs 5665423567888 times in a row but never again, etc.

Comment: Oops, you are right, I meant a constant sequence, or a sequence that just consists of one value.