# Prove a sequence converges to a

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Let {$a_n$} be a sequence such that there exist numbers b and N such that for n $\ge$ N, $a_n$ = b. Prove that {$a_n$} converges to b.

I am not sure how to go about this question. The information we are given does look very similar to the definition of convergence, but I'm not quite sure how to prove this given the information available.

Any help would be appreciated, I will try to answer comments as soon as possible.

Comment: Check this: [Convergence of a constant sequence and an eventually constant sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511068/42969).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is given that there exists an $N$ such that for any $n\ge N$ we have $a_n=b$ so for any $\epsilon>0$

$|b - b| = 0 <\epsilon$ which means that $a_n\to b$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: You all are very fast! Thank you :)

Comment: If you chose my answer as your favorite I gain extra points ;)

Comment: Ha sorry, I wouldn't let me at first because it was too soon after. I have rectified it :)